# Вызов вариативного товара Woocommerce

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

Всем привет! Необходимо вызвать вариативный товар в собственном php шаблоне. Делаю это впервые, поэтому скорее всего не правильно. Смог вызвать название, цену, короткое описание, описание, но не понимаю, как вызвать его изображение, вариации (атрибут, выбор цвета) и кнопку купить.

Необходимо, чтобы при смене вариации, также менялось изображение. На странице самого продукта это работает из коробки, но мне нужно вывести в собственном шаблоне. Прошу, подскажите и если не сложно, покажите какой то пример.

```html
<section id="bags" class="section">
  <div class="container">
    <?php 
      $args = array('post_type' => 'product', 'post_id' => 25); 
      $posts = get_posts($args);
      $product = new WC_Product_Variable( 25 );
      foreach($posts as $post) { ?>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 bags-thumbnail">
          <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 bags-content">
          <h2 class="bags-title"><?php echo get_the_title( $post->ID ); ?></h2>
          <span class="bags-short-description"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></span>
          <span class="bags-price"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></span>о
          <?php echo $product->get_description(); ?>
        </div>
      </div>
    <?php } ?>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Все верно используете, что вас не устраивает?

Comment: Все устраивает, работает, но не понимаю, как вывести изображение, вариации (атрибут, выбор цвета) и кнопку купить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил вопрос гораздо проще. Нашел шорткод, который выводит страницу товара там, где нужно.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[product_page id="25"]'); ?>
```